# ExtJS config members with getter or setter only

Tags: javascript, extjs, getter, setter

How can I create config members with a `getter` or `setter` only but not both at the same time?

By default it creates both a `getter` and `setter`.

```
Ext.define('Myapp.myclass', {
   config: {
      conf1 : true,  // Make this only have setter.
      conf2 : false  // Make this only have getter.
   },

   constructor: function(config) {
       this.apply(config);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configs actually create 4 helper methods, which are quite useful.

```
_config1             this is where the value gets saved
getConfig1           gets you the value
applyConfig1         allows you to check if the setter value is valid
updateConfig1        do some stuff to dom elements
setConfig1           call applyConfig1 and updateConfig1 if available and set the value to _config1. Usually you dont want to touch this, but use updateConfig1
```

If you do not want these then you have to do the work yourself, but you might not get bindables or other ExtJS out of the box functionality. For me it does not make a lot of sense not to use configs.

```
Ext.define('Myapp.myclass', {
    _conf1: true,  // Make this only have setter.
    setConfig1: function(value) {
        let oldValue = this._config1;

        if(oldValue === value) return;

        this._config1 = value;
    },

    _conf2: true,  // Make this only have getter.
    getConfig2: function() {
        return this._config2;
    }
});
```